# Submitting concurrent HTTP requests with RestSharp

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I have a RESTful API running as a self hosted OWIN application, and a Client that's making API calls to the server. Both are done using .Net/WebAPI/RestSharp. In a normal scenario the client sends an HTTP request and receives an HTTP response and everything works as expected. However, there are cases when the client needs to send another request before receiving a response from the previous request. Something like:

- ```
  HTTP POST Request1  <-- this is a long running operation on the server side
  ```
- ```
    HTTP POST Request2 <-- this comes from a different thread
  ```
- ```
    HTTP POST Response2
  ```
- ```
  HTTP POST Response1
  ```

The problem is that Request2 doesn't send until Response1 arrives. These requests are blocking calls (synchronous) and I cannot make them asynchronous.

I tried setting System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 20 before initializing my RestClient, but that didn't help.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;    
var Client = new RestClient("https://someURL");
```

Any idea on what the problem might be? and what can I do to send those requests concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

This was a thread synchronization issue in my server. I was dealing with a deadlock situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using **RestClient.ExecuteAsync()** instead of **.Execute()** may solve the problem.